# Update values in pairwise pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply

I have a pairwise df:

```
raw_data = {0: [5,4,6,8,9], 
        1: [4,8,1,2,5], 
        2: [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        3: [0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
        4: [2, 2, 0, 2, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = [0,1,2,3,4])
```

I want to set any zero to the value of its pair, for example theres a 0 at col 0 row 3 so its pair would be at col 3 row 0 which is value 8 in this example.

I can do it by iteration:

```
for i in df.index:
    for j in df.columns:
        if df.loc[i,j] == 0:
            df.loc[i,j] = df.loc[j,i]
```

But its slow. Can I apply a function or a df method to do this quickly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign it by Boolean

```
df[df==0]=df.T
df
Out[364]: 
   0  1   2   3   4
0  5  4  42   8   2
1  4  8  52   2   2
2  6  1  36  24  73
3  8  2  24   2   2
4  9  5  73   1   0
```

Comment: @LiamMcIntyre df==0 this will return boolean , then we can assign the value to the True value

Answer (score 3):

Call replace 0s with NaNs and `pd.DataFrame.fillna` using the transpose of `df`.

```
df[df != 0].fillna(df.T).astype(int)

   0  1   2   3   4
0  5  4  42   8   2
1  4  8  52   2   2
2  6  1  36  24  73
3  8  2  24   2   2
4  9  5  73   1   0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `where/mask` we nullify where the first argument is `True` and fill it in with the alternative in the second argument.

```
df.where(df.astype(bool), df.T)
```

Or,

```
df.mask(df.eq(0), df.T)
```

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   5   4   6   8   9
1   4   8   1   2   5
2  42  52  36  24  73
3   8   2  24   2   1
4   2   2  73   2   0
```

---

And per [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837373/update-values-in-pairwise-pandas-df/49837765?noredirect=1#comment86690736_49837765)'s suggestion, the Numpy equivalent

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(df, df, df.T), df.index, df.columns)

    0   1   2   3   4
0   5   4   6   8   9
1   4   8   1   2   5
2  42  52  36  24  73
3   8   2  24   2   1
4   2   2  73   2   0
```

Comment: Ah this is so elegant. You can add the numpy equivalent too `pd.DataFrame(np.where(df == 0, df.T, df))`

Comment: I tweaked it a tiny bit

Comment: Nice, forgot numpy could test the truthiness of ints (unlike pandas which _needs_ a boolean mask).